# Preventing super class function overriding in subclass

Tags: php

Is their any way to prevent function overriding of a super class  in subclass. if yes please let me know. thanks in advance.

Comment: Final function : http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`final`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php) keyword:

Examples:

```
class CanBeInherited {
    public final function cantBeInherited() {
         ...
    }
}

final class CannotBeInherited {
    public function cantBeInheritedEither() {
         ...
    }
}

class Child extends CanBeInherited { } //This is fine
class Child2 extends CanBeInherited { 
    public function cantBeInherited() {} //Error
}
class Child3 extends CannotBeInherited {} //Error
```

Comment: can you please let me know why this line is error.   class Child3 extends CantBeParent {}

Comment: Because `CantBeParent` is `final` and therefore can't be parent (because that's what final means for a class).

Comment: got it. Thank you.(i didnt see that child3 is extending from cantbeparent, i thought it is canbeparent).

Comment: @Sucharitha good point. I've renamed it to make it a bit more clear that it's not the same

Answer (score 1):

declare function in this way in super class

```
class Foo
{
    final public function bar()
    {
        //Do action A
    }
}
```